# What does it mean to "measure a stabilizer"?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Say I have the stabilizer $XXI$, and a phase-flipped state $|\psi\rangle$. What does it mean to measure the stabilizer $XXI$?

What is the math behind "measurement"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Measurements can be described by a Hermitian operator, $A$. In this case, $A=X\otimes X\otimes I$. That operator has a spectral decomposition
$$
A=\sum_i\lambda_iP_i,
$$
where the $\lambda_i$ are the distinct (real) eigenvalues, and the $P_i$ are projectors onto the different eigenspaces, and satisfy the completeness relation $\sum_iP_i=I$.

So, basically, we're using $A$ to define the set $\{P_i\}$ which are the projectors in the formalism of projective measurement, i.e. we measure in this basis and get answer $i$ with probability $p_i=\langle\psi|P_i|\psi\rangle$. After the measurement, the system is in the state $P_i|\psi\rangle/\sqrt{p_i}$.

In your case, since $A^2=I$, you know the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, and hence you can write
$$
P_{\pm}=\frac12(I\pm A).
$$